# questions on KVM(JVM)

Tags: java, java-me

is it possible different KVMs in different mobiles?who is the owner of that KVM(sun or others?suppose if i want manufacture GSM mobile,how can it support j2me applications,
i have to get permissions from sun micro systems to purchase KVM(kilobyte virtual machine)
can anyone give answer in detail?

Answer (score 3):

J2ME virtual machines do tend to be based off of Sun's reference implementation - depending on your platform you can either license 3rd-party adaptations of this (Windows Mobile, Palm, etc)or you can roll your own from Sun's sources.

Which way you go depends on many factors, including:

- VM license cost (one-off or yearly, this is negotiated and is out of reach of individuals)
- Runtime license cost (total cost also negotiable, depends on your expected shipping volumes)
- JSR implementation licensing (J2ME profiles are made from a wide variety of specific JSR implementations for things like video, 3d, svg, etc) - pricing varies from one-off to runtime-based.

Sun also makes available a GPL version of the J2ME VM reference implementation - it's **VERY IMPORTANT** to understand how the GPL license affects software in the embedded industry; talk to a lawyer about this if it's an option you're considering.

In a lot of cases, it's simply easier to ask your GSM mobile vendor to price up a J2ME option on top of your bare platform OS deal.